# cx_Freeze Exe Application closes as soon as it opens without any error

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have developed a tkinter gui application and converted it into exe using cx_Freeze.

The exe file was working fine. But after some days when I try to open it, it is starting the application and closes immediately. Also I tried creating the bat file to see if any error is thrown. But there was no error.
After all this I tried to generate a new build once again with the same setup file. It worked well and the application is opening properly. But I don't know what is the problem with the old one.

Please help me if anyone has seen this weird behavior.

For Reference I copy my setup file below:

```
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = 'C:/Program Files/Python3.6/tcl/tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = 'C:/Program Files/Python3.6/tcl/tk8.6'

buildOptions = dict(
    packages = ["pandas","tkinter","numpy","pandatables","Images"],
    excludes = [],
    include_files=['C:/Program Files/Python3.6/DLLs/tcl86t.dll', 'C:/Program Files/Python3.6/DLLs/tk86t.dll']
)

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
    Executable('DE.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='DE Validator',
      version = '1.0',
      description = '',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)'
```

Comment: Which version of `cx_Freeze` are you using?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I am using cx_Freeze-5.1.1

Answer (score 1):

For `cx_Freeze` version 5.1.1, the TCL/TK DLLs need to be included in a `lib` subdirectory of the build directory. You can do that by passing a tuple `(source, destination)` to the corresponding entry of the `include_files` list option.

Furthermore, it would be safer to dynamically find out the location of the TCL/TK DLLs.

Try to modify your setup script as follows:

```py
import sys

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

buildOptions = dict(
    packages = ["pandas","tkinter","numpy","pandatables","Images"],
    excludes = [],
    include_files=[(os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
                    os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll')),
                   (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
                    os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll'))]
)
```